# Unable to render the right component in a specific route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to render the **LoginForm** component in the route "**/login**". However, when I click on the **LOG IN** link in the header, the URL endpoint doesn't change and the **Products** component gets rendered.
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

The code snippets are given below:
App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import SingleProductView from "./components/SingleProductView";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";
import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" component={SingleProductView} />
            <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={Cart} />
            <Route path="/" component={Products} exact />
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" collapseOnSelect>
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand>ProShop</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
              <LinkContainer to="/cart">
                <Nav.Link>
                  <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>cart
                </Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/login">
                <Nav.Link>
                  <i className="fa fa-user"></i>Log In
                </Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: I have created an ugly, but working example according to your code. It works fine for me and it seems correct. So probably threre is a problem on other parts of your code (https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-cannon-ll8d9?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

you must import `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` and wrap all of your routes with the `BrowserRouter` Component.

Comment: I am doing that in Index.js. ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Answer (score 0):

Just update this import statement in `App.js`
`import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";`

And Update this piece of code in App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>

 <Switch>
       <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" component=. {SingleProductView} />
        <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={Cart} />
        <Route path="/" component={Products} exact />
</Switch>

</BrowserRouter>
```